# Create/Use Project in VS Code via Terminal

Tags: terminal

I have a remote ubuntu machine that I use from my mac only via terminal.

I have installed VS Code in it via the command: `snap install --classic code`

However, I am confused as to how do I start creating or using projects in it. I create a new folder "Project" then I go inside it (cd Project) and then hit the command `code`. Nothing happens. I try `code .` . Again, nothing happens. I am confused as to how do I go about it.

Could anyone please help me on how to start creating and using projects in VS Code available in my remote Ubuntu Machine via only terminal?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to use Visual Studio Code as a in-terminal editor without the graphical user interface that the editor usually presents?

Comment: Yup, is it possible? @Kusalananda